# Scrollview overlaps part of the text

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, scrollview

I need help.
At work, I was given a task to figure out why ScrollView overlaps part of the text. The layout is multi-layered, and I think the problem lies in this. I'm new to android studio and it's still hard for me to understand the relationships of all objects.

[image]

all the XML is here  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PaGIWPn2w6ubZraVpQfq8Rrqo0uCWYOiIbxnCWaIKTQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
below is a part of the code
```

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|left|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainBlackColor"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    tools:text="Сообщение" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/red"
                    android:lines="3"
                    android:paddingStart="3dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                    android:paddingRight="3dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/mainTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18dp"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="10dp"
                    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="4dp"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    tools:text="Детали"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` and `padding_horizontal` to your `scrollView`. This should solve your issue.